# Testing beforeFilter() function

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp-3.0

I am doing unit testing for a PHP application using CakePHP framework. 
The function that I am testing is beforeFilter() which basically loads the models.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);

        $this->loadModel('Model1');
        $this->loadModel('Model2');
        $this->loadModel('Model3');
        $this->loadModel('Model3');

}
```

How should I test this function ? What assertions I need to make in order to write good test case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about not loading all the tables in the beforeFilter? It would make more sense loading in the places you need.

In the case that is absolutely necessary to load them, you would test it like this:

```
$controller = new Controller
...
$controller->beforeFilter($event);
$this->assertInstanceOf($controller->Model1 \App\Model\Table\Model1Table);
...
```